# Excel 2016 vba ADODB with MySQL

Tags: mysql, excel, odbc

Hi I need to connect to a MySQL DB from excel, I found this example:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,100302

modify it to my requirements, but at the time of run it does nothing, nor it gives me error.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub excelmysql()
' VBA to perform various actions on MySQL tables using VBA
' Majority of the original code adapted from Carlmack http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=46893

' PLEASE DO THE FOLLOWING BEFORE EXECUTING CODE:
' 1)In VBE you need to go Tools/References and check Microsoft Active X Data Objects 2.x library
' 2)Install MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver. See dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/3.51.html or google "MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver"

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Connection variables
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim server_name As String
Dim database_name As String
Dim user_id As String
Dim password As String

' Table action variables
Dim i As Long ' counter
Dim sqlstr As String ' SQL to perform various actions
Dim table1 As String, table2 As String
Dim field1 As String, field2 As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim vtype As Variant

'----------------------------------------------------------------------
' Establish connection to the database
server_name = "127.0.0.1" ' Enter your server name here - if running from a local computer use 127.0.0.1
database_name = "pruebas" ' Enter your database name here
user_id = "prueba" ' enter your user ID here
password = "12345678" ' Enter your password here

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}" _
& ";SERVER=" & server_name _
& ";DATABASE=" & database_name _
& ";UID=" & user_id _
& ";PWD=" & password _
& ";OPTION=16427" ' Option 16427 = Convert LongLong to Int: This just helps makes sure that large numeric results get properly interpreted

'---------------------------------------------
' Extract MySQL table data to first worksheet in the workbook
GoTo skipextract
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
sqlstr = "select dato1 from datos where IdDato=1" ' extracts all data
rs.Open sqlstr, conn, adOpenStatic
With Worksheets("Hoja1").Cells("A1") ' Enter your sheet name and range here
.ClearContents
.CopyFromRecordset rs
End With
skipextract:

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------
' Close connections
On Error Resume Next
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

I much appreciate your attention and time.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
GoTo skipextract
```

is bypassing where you actually query the database. It takes the application to the rows where you close the connection and drop the variables. I imagine that its an error from copying and should have been

```
On Error GoTo skipextract
```

So that it captures any connection errors and closes the connection. But if no errors come up it queries as you intended.